# How to stop eclipse re-building other projects when trying to run one project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm having annoying issue with eclipse. I have 20+ project in my eclipse (maven, gradle). Which has 10,000+ files in resources path each. I turned off "Build Automatically" in eclipse menu. When I try to run one project's java. It suddenly started doing cleaning workspace for Project1, and copying resource to target directory for project1, and continue to project n then it's starting the application which I intended to start. The beauty is I was trying to start a node application and it's trying to do clean and build for Project 1 to n which are maven or gradle. Is it a defect in eclipse or is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: How do you *start a node application* ? through Eclipse?

Comment: Have you tried closing all the other projects?

Comment: @nullpointer That's hilarious man, you have to start using "eclipse market" :D

Comment: @weichihung Yep that will work I know that, but basically, I'm concerned about eclipse build logic. Why it needs to clean and build other project.

Comment: @Pasupathi If you know which project is causing it, see the list of builders: _Project > Properties: Builders_. I guess it is a third-party plug-in (at least that's what happened to me once). Eclipse build logic is to build also referenced projects (and from these the referenced projects etc.): _Project > Properties: Project References_. But a third-party project builder can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @Pasupathi Well I meant what are your run configurations when you start the application?

Comment: @howlger I have `java builder` and `gradle project builder`

Comment: @nullpointer Run configuration of my app.js is `Node.js Application`

Comment: @Pasupathi First you have to find the project that causes the issue by trying to close/open projects and then look which builders the causing project has (not the project that contains the code to run). When the problem disappears by closing other project, it is caused by one or more of the projects that have been closed.

Comment: @howlger My projects can be classified by Maven and gradle. All Maven and gradle projects are going for rebuild, as it's doing workspace rebuild.

Comment: @Pasupathi Unrelated projects are not build on _Project > Build Project_. If _Build Automatically_ is disabled, in the _Clean_ dialog there is a checkbox _Start a build immediately_ at the bottom with the two options _Build the entire workspace_ and _Build only the selected projects_. Make sure you chose the second option. I tested it with Oxygen.1 and with Gradle and Maven projects, but I was not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @howlger Still happening in Oxygen too. I changed compiler from 1.6 to 1.8 and it started cleaning target(maven) and bin (gradle) started rebuilding all open projects.

Comment: @Pasupathi At some point a project and all projects that can influence the project has to be built in order to run it. _Build Automatically_ means (incremental) build on save instead of before running a launch configuration. To turn of builders uncheck all builders in each project: _Project > Properties: Builders_. You could also consider to isolate sets of projects from each other in different workspaces.